# Using Hover makes the div bounce

Tags: jquery

I am using hover in the following way:

```
    $('.item a').hover(function () {
        $('#overlay').slideDown();
    }, function () {
        $('#overlay').slideUp();
    });
```

However as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/v644X/, it makes the animation bounce. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the `hover` event for that `overlay` too. And don't forget to clear the `animation queue (.stop)` on every time you are beginning a new one,

Just try,

```
        $('.item a,#overlay').hover(function () {
            $('#overlay').stop().slideDown();
        }, function () {
            $('#overlay').stop().slideUp();
        });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v644X/2/)

---

**Identified hack:**

In the other answer, if you get your mouse out from the `a` element very fast, then you can see the overlay is still being appeared.

For better hackles version you can use,

```
        var overlay = $('#overlay');

        $('.item a,#overlay').hover(function () {
            if(!overlay.is(':animated')){
                overlay.stop().slideDown();
            }
        }, function () {
            if(!overlay.is(':animated')){
            overlay.stop().slideUp();
            }
        });
```

### [DEMO I](http://jsfiddle.net/v644X/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.item a').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#overlay').stop().slideDown();
});
$('#overlay').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).stop().slideUp();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XLd7y/)

Comment: Thanks but why not do it using hover? Is there a specific reason you have asked me to replace with mouseenter/leave?